# ¿Cómo agregar un servidor de correo en Docker-Compose?

Tags: mysql, docker, nginx, docker-compose, traefik2

Estoy levantando mi web en `wordpress` con `docker` y tengo un problema que no he podido solucionar.

tengo los siguientes contenedores:

```
traefik
wordpress
nginx
mysql
phpmyadmin
```

cuando levanto estos contenedores todo funciona bien, sin embargo, cuando quiero agregar mi servidor de correo con la imagen `analogic/poste.io` para gestionar los mails de mi dominio, la base de datos de se cae automáticamente y los servicios dejan de funcionar, tengo entendido que esta imagen, según la documentación trabaja con `nginx` y `mysqli` por lo que creo que esto puede estar causado el problema ya que puede haber un conflicto con alguno de estos servicios.

si bien es cierto, entiendo cual puede ser el problema que causa que mi `mysql` deje de funcionar, pero no sé como solucionar esto en mi `docker-compose`.

```
version: "3.7"
services: 
  
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.1
    container_name: traefik
    ports: 
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    volumes: 
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./traefik.yml:/traefik.yml
      - ./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.midominio.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=myresolver
      - traefik.port=8080
      - traefik.docker.network=web
    networks:
      - web

  #MAILSERVER
  correo:
    image: analogic/poste.io
    container_name: correo
    restart: always
    labels: 
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.correo.rule=Host(`correo.midominio.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.correo.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.correo.tls.certresolver=myresolver
    expose:
      - 25
      - 110
      - 143
      - 465
      - 587
      - 993
      - 995
    volumes: 
      - ./data-correo:/data
    environment:
      - HTTPS=ON
    networks:
      - web  

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${MYSQL_USER}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
    labels: 
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=3306"
    volumes: 
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - web

  wp:
    build:
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: wp
    labels: 
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.wp.rule=Host(`midominio.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.wp.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.wp.tls.certresolver=myresolver
      - traefik.port=9000
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "${WORDPRESS_DB_USER}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD}"
    networks:
      - web
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: wp-nginx
    depends_on: 
      - wp
    labels: 
      - traefik.port=80
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./conf.d/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - web  

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: ${PMA_HOST}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin.rule=Host(`pa.midominio.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.phpmyadmin.tls.certresolver=myresolver
      - traefik.port=80
    networks:
      - web 

networks:
  web:
   driver: "bridge"
```

Aquí estàn los contenedores

```
Name                 Command                   State                                                 Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
correo       /init                            Up (unhealthy)   110/tcp, 143/tcp, 25/tcp, 4190/tcp, 443/tcp, 465/tcp, 587/tcp, 80/tcp, 993/tcp, 995/tcp
db           docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Exit 137
phpmyadmin   /docker-entrypoint.sh apac ...   Up               80/tcp
traefik      /entrypoint.sh traefik           Up               0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
wp           docker-entrypoint.sh apach ...   Up               80/tcp, 9000/tcp
wp-nginx     /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up               80/tcp
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, Muchas Gracias :)

se agregan logs de mysql

```
Attaching to db
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.252487Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.253590Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.22) starting as process 1 ...
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.262179Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.262197Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.262200Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.262202Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.262204Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.262206Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.262832Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.264050Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.265977Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.276860Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.280073Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.298403Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.299624Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 14845981
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.299632Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 14845990
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.299635Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.299637Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.444263Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.444299Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.444337Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.466464Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.467133Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.467139Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.467430Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.517634Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.22 started; log sequence number 14845990
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.517999Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.518180Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.532429Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.538734Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.545331Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200728 18:35:09
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.547015Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.548121Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.548381Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.548517Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.551100Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.554037Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.554064Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.554069Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.554188Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.554192Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.554312Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.566039Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.566072Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.584530Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db               | 2020-07-28T18:35:09.584676Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db               | Version: '5.7.22'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.178563Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.183411Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.22) starting as process 1 ...
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.188342Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.188425Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.188473Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.188503Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.188527Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.188569Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.189276Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.190523Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.192347Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.199632Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.201442Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.223469Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.224793Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 14846352
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.224848Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 14846361
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.224876Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.224917Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.354955Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.355174Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.355281Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.372580Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.373379Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.373430Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.373731Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.423890Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.22 started; log sequence number 14846361
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.424122Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.424458Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.432021Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.432552Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200728 20:09:08
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.432902Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.436375Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.437425Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.437483Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.437547Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.439641Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.441433Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.441506Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.441553Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.441677Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.441717Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.441835Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.447081Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.447137Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.464044Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db               | 2020-07-28T20:09:08.464281Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db               | Version: '5.7.22'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.046329Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.052572Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.22) starting as process 1 ...
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.059437Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.059514Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.059558Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.059592Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.059617Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.059655Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.060298Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.061592Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.064617Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.075810Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.086695Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.103887Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.105356Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 14890778
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.105416Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 14890787
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.105448Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.105495Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.239800Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.240026Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.240108Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.261631Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.262419Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.262470Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.262764Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.312937Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.22 started; log sequence number 14890787
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.313359Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.313595Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.322435Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.327343Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200728 20:13:44
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.329647Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.333343Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.334511Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.334698Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.334758Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.337052Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.339466Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.339538Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.339585Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.339733Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.339771Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.339897Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.345805Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.345861Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.362048Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db               | 2020-07-28T20:13:44.362268Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db               | Version: '5.7.22'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

agrega logs de poste.io

```
correo           | (node:644) [DEP0123] DeprecationWarning: Setting the TLS ServerName to an IP address is not permitted by RFC 6066. This will be ignored in a future version.
correo           |     at new connect (_tls_wrap.js:1610:15)
correo           |     at pluggableStream.socket.upgrade (/usr/lib/node_modules/Haraka/tls_socket.js:713:27)
correo           |     at pluggableStream.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/Haraka/outbound/hmail.js:813:28)
correo           |     at pluggableStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
correo           |     at pluggableStream.on_socket_data (/usr/lib/node_modules/Haraka/line_socket.js:25:20)
correo           |     at pluggableStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
correo           |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/Haraka/tls_socket.js:59:18)
correo           |     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
correo           |     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
correo           |     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
```

Comment: Podrias mostrar los logs que te tira el container de db? `docker-compose logs db`

Comment: Hola @NicolasAcosta he editado la pregunta y agregue el logs de mysql.

Comment: Pues no pinta que se caiga nada en la BD; pareciera más un conflicto en los puertos -de los de toda la vida-. Revisa los logs para el contenedor que levantas al final, el de correo

Comment: Edite la pregunta y agregue el logs del contenedor de correo y noto un error pero no se como se puede solucionar.

Comment: El exit code 137 es out of memory. Comprueba que no estés consumiendo toda tu ram al añadir el nuevo servicio

Comment: Estimado @nax Efectivamente el problema era que estaba trabajando en un servidor que tenia poca memoria para correr todos estos servicios, por lo tanto la solución fue aumentar la ram y todo funciona de maravilla, saludos y gracias por responder.